# How to derive this proportional conditional probability

Tags: time-series, conditional-probability

In the book Bayesian Data Analysis 3rd edition by Gelman et al., the solution for task 3.15 on time series data involves the following expression:

$$p(y_t|y_{t-1})p(y_{t+1}|y_t) \propto p(y_t|y_{t-1}, y_{t+1})$$

This means that $y_t$ depends only on $y_{t-1}$ and $y_{t+1}$. But how do I derive the right-hand side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the defintion of conditional probability to get this formula:

$$
\begin{align}
P(y_{t+1}, y_t, y_{t-1}) &= P(y_{t+1}|y_t, y_{t-1}) \cdot P(y_t, y_{t-1})\\
&=P(y_{t+1}|y_t, y_{t-1}) \cdot P(y_t| y_{t-1})\cdot P(y_{t-1})\\
\end{align}
$$

If you assume Markove process, you have $P(y_{t+1}|y_t, y_{t-1}) = P(y_{t+1}|y_t)$.

Plugging the formula, we get
$$
P(y_{t+1}, y_t, y_{t-1}) =P(y_{t+1}|y_t) \cdot P(y_t| y_{t-1})\cdot P(y_{t-1})\\
$$

You  can expand the original probability $P(y_{t+1}, y_t, y_{t-1})$ in this way also:
$$
\begin{align}
P(y_{t+1}, y_t, y_{t-1}) &= P(y_{t}|y_{t+1}, y_{t-1}) \cdot P(y_{t+1}, y_{t-1})\\
&=P(y_{t}|y_{t+1}, y_{t-1})  \cdot P(y_{t+1}| y_{t-1})\cdot P(y_{t-1})\\
\end{align}
$$

Under a Markove process hypothesis, $y_{t+1}$ doesn't depend on $y_{t-1}$. Therefore,
we have $P(y_{t+1}| y_{t-1}) = P(y_{t+1})$.

Equating two equations, we have
$$
P(y_{t+1}|y_t) \cdot P(y_t| y_{t-1})\cdot P(y_{t-1}) = P(y_{t}|y_{t+1}, y_{t-1})  \cdot P(y_{t+1})\cdot P(y_{t-1})
$$

Cancelling the term $P(y_{t-1})$, we arrive at this equation:

$$
P(y_{t+1}|y_t) \cdot P(y_t| y_{t-1}) = P(y_{t}|y_{t+1}, y_{t-1})  \cdot P(y_{t+1})
$$